# button not going inside div?

Tags: css, layout, containers

I have a button div, and inside there is an img, and button. I am trying to get the img on top of the button inside of the div, centered in my FacebookDivv.

```
<div id="FacebookDivv">
     <div id="buttonDiv">
         <button id="loginBut" ><p id="SignInText">Sign In</p></button>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/alecive/flatwoken/512/Apps-Facebook-icon.png" height="150px" width="150px" margin-top="50vh">
    </div>
    </div>
```

and my css is:

```
 #loginBut {
        border-color: #2d5073;
        background-color: #3b5998;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 120px;

        background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/512/facebook-icon.png);
        background: url(http://aroosamanzar.com/uploads/images/facebook-logo-png-white-i6.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4c74c4), color-stop(100%, #3b5998));
        background-size: 25px 25px, cover;
        background-position: 170px center, center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    }

    #buttonDiv{
        width: 150px;
        align-content: center;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 40vh;
    }
```

when I load the page the button is besdie the img and inspecting src says it is not even within the buttonDiv?

Answer (score 1):

Erase that `p` tag inside the `button` tag in the HTML, and if you want the image insode the button, use it as a background-image, not in an `img` tag

Comment: I want a div containing an img and a button, with the button formated under the div

Comment: under the buttonDiv

Comment: right now the button is INSIDE the buttonDiv, i.e. it will appear in the button DIV.

Comment: my bad problem was with javascript appending the button beside it.